# Screen becomes fuzzy (Ubuntu Studio 22.04)

Tags: plasma, ubuntu-studio, 22.04

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04. Proprietary nvidia drivers 510.60.02. The screen will sometimes get fuzzy. It's not constant and doing things like typing or moving the mouse will cause it to become un-fuzzy briefly.

Logging out of my X session and logging back in fixes it.

The two times I've noticed it happening the triggers appear to be either exiting a game or after the screen/screensaver has been on a long time (over night).

I'm actually able to screenshot it, which is interesting, so here's what I see: [Fuzzy Ubuntu Studio 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTIOq.jpg)

Comment: Ok, so interesting development. After the screen had been locked for a while I unlocked and things were fuzzy. On a whim I decided to start a game to see what would happen with the fuzziness. As soon as I launched the game the fuzziness went away. What does this mean? I have no idea!

Comment: Additional update. It's heavily modded Battletech which sometimes needs killing. I killed it and the fuzziness came back immediately. Restarted the game and fuzziness is gone again. I still don't know what that means, but any and all data should hopefully be useful to someone!